# how to perform automatic button click?

Tags: buttonclick

Is there any idea on how to create a program (in any programming language) that clicks on a given button of a software that has buttons to be clicked ?
The software in question is programmed by a third party (I have not its code source).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use AutoHotKey. Look an example on [this page](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm).

More complicated way is to use WinAPI. You can get a handle of interest window. Then you need to get handle to interest button on this window. Then you would send WM_CLICK message to them. Like that:

```
HWND window, button;
window= FindWindow("Caption of interest window",NULL);
button= FindWindowEx(window,0,"Button",NULL);
PostMessage(button,WM_CLICK,0,0);
```